# How to separate out a long list of verbs that then merges in with long list of objects?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Imagine the following example:

> Feminists destroy, reduce, decimate, deconstruct, defame, destabilize, and fragment the female culture, history, sexuality, identity, reality, and truth.

In the above example, after "fragment" the author is done using verbs and has started a long list of words (objects, subjects?) that are the things that the previous verbs will be acting on.

The actual sentence that I read somewhere is quite similar to the above but in that case the author is using even a more complex sentence where she groups several words together, like she writes in the second part, "culture, history, and tradition" separated by semi-colon and then "body, sexuality, and gender", etc.  But I decided to keep it simple for my question here.

Please assume one is interested in keeping the sentence long and don't break it up into small parts.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any "author" who wrote that sentence is not worthy of the name. It reads like a trainwreck of verbs, as though an angry teenager has just discovered a thesaurus. Is the rest of the piece this bad?

Comment: Don't keep it simple, copy the exact sentence as it is written and cite your source. A link would be helpful too.  @mikeagg correctly points out that the simplified version is just plain awful.

Comment: The sentence that you provided is grammatically fine.  I'm torn between "It's terrible writing." and "I'm fascinated by it."  It has a certain power to it.

Comment: There is no actual question in the body of your lengthy question text; and the question in your question title hinges on the words "separate out" and "merges in," both of which I'm having trouble understanding in the context of the questionless question body. Hence my vote to close the question as "unclear what you're asking."